# Add default meta data to a page/post template

Tags: templates, post-meta, block-editor

Creating a Gutenberg template and populating it with default content is as simple as defining the initial content inside a file of the templates directory of a theme and the defining said template in theme.json.

Is it also possible to define default meta field values if that meta data has been registered?

It can obviously be done on php via `functions.php` or any of its require files but can it be done directly in the theme's templates directory?

Say we have inside templates directory `showpage.html` and the theme has registered a post meta string of `template_class`. Can we set `showpage.html` to set `template_class` to `showpageclass` by default?